# Remove all Invalid Fields from ALL Lists

Tags: list, upgrade, sharepoint-fields

I'm upgrading our sharepoint from 2007 to 2013 and I'm running into an issue where 
the Field type is not installed properly. Removing that column from one list is easy and can be done through the website, but I would like to remove this field from all the lists in all the sites. Is there an easy powershell script to do this?

[image: Error]

[image: Invalid]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the Correlation Id  log

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scripting this out I added the outdated `.wsp` solutions correctly before upgrading the database. This correctly installed the  corrupted field.

> You can get add these solutions using powershell or the admin console.
>   I used powershell with the following commands

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath <path>.wsp
Install-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script will help to delete fields form sharepoint list. if you want to automate then create CSV file which has List Name's and Fields.

Pass that CSV as input to the below script.

```
#Load SharePoint User Profile assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") | out-null
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue

#Global variables
$webUrl = "http://wwblrsp2013:1515/sites/OldRC/"
#List Name
$ListName = "PollQuestions"
# Deleted Field Name
$fieldName = "Test"

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl 
$list = $spWeb.Lists[$ListName]
$listFields = $list.Fields
$listFields.Delete($fieldName);
$list.Update();
```